# How to animate a Button nested within a `.navigationBarItems`

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to animate a button whenever it's tapped. The following code works so far

```
NavigationView {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.showDetail.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0))
                    .scaleEffect(showDetail ? 1.5 : 1)
                    .padding()
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I move it into a `NavigationView`'s `navigationBarItems`, it stops working; it simply snaps to the size and rotation. How do I fix this?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Does not work")
            }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showDetail.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0))
                            .scaleEffect(showDetail ? 1.5 : 1)
                            .padding()
                            .animation(.spring())
                    }
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something odd is going on. If you add an onAppear() to your Image and log something to the console, you'll see that its closure executes every time you tap on it. It seems as if it gets destroyed and recreated every time, which is probably what causes the animation problem. :-( bug?

Comment: I see. I guess it's to be expected since SwiftUI IS still in beta. Either that or this is intended. I guess we'll find out in a few months